# Can Canada still become part of the USA?

Tags: united-states, constitution, canada

I read that in the Constitution it was stated that if Canada wanted to become part of the US, they would be accepted fully. First off, is that true? Building off that, if they wanted to be part of the US, would they be accepted, or would they be kinda, but not really (think of Guam )?

Comment: The countries *could* agree to merge, but then a lot of Canadians would lose healthcare coverage and a lot of Americans would lose their escape route after an election that doesn't go their way.

Comment: This question should probably be renamed, since the focus seems to be on constitutional-basis for admitting Canada to the US, and not on a process like how Hawaii or Alaska joined the union.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, that option expired in 1788.

The [Articles of Confederation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articles_of_Confederation) had, as clause XI:

> Canada acceding to this confederation, and adjoining in the measures of the United States, shall be admitted into, and entitled to all the advantages of this Union; but no other colony shall be admitted into the same, unless such admission be agreed to by nine States.

When the Articles were replaced by the current Constitution, that clause was dropped, since Canada clearly wasn't interested.

Comment: And the *colony* of Canada described in the Articles of Confederation no longer exists anyway...

Comment: @DJohnM - Very true.  I just asked a question [over on History](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/33221/2204) to see if either of the successor provinces would have been able to lay claim to this clause (if it hadn't been removed).